# How to backup and restore databases through stored procedure in Azure SQL using Elastic Pool?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, database-backups, database-restore, azure-elasticpool

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC based web application in which there is a functionality of Archiving (backup) and Restoring Databases on the click of button. Currently, our system is On-Prem and so we are using the stored procedures in SQL Server to do the backup and restore.

Now we are migrating to Azure PaaS and are using Elastic Pool. As the backup and restore T-SQL commands do not work in **Azure SQL**, so can someone please help me in finding a way to do the **backup and restore** of DBs manually through **T-SQL**?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Auto backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups) is a feature of Azure SQL database.
[image]

In SQL Azure, database backups are executed automatically and it is not possible to change this behavior. This is a service offered when you create a SQL Azure database and the first full backup occurs immediately after you create a new SQL Azure database and the rest of the backups are scheduled by SQL Azure itself.

There is no way can help you backup and restore of DBs manually through T-SQL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @HafsaKhan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer,Leon! :)

So that it could be helpful to other community members, I would like to mention another way to achieve the same as it can't be done by T-SQL.

What I have done instead is, I have used SQLPackage.exe utility embedded in a batch script and executed that batch script through my C# code to achieve the same functionality.